# fmt seems to be behaving strangely when there are percent characters in the string, but

Tags: go

something very strange i dont know how to explain.    I ran the following in play.golang.org: (after seeing another q/a thread)

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    str := "Uid $LKE '%1234%'"
    sp := fmt.Sprintf("20: %s\n", str)
    fmt.Println(sp)
}
```

it printed correctly (as expected).

```
 20: Uid $LKE '%1234%'
```

when i included the exact same code in my http Handler function, it prints:

```
 20: Uid $LKE '%'
```

Is there anything environmental (or something) in go that I may be stupidly doing to short-circuit getting the expected?  I'm using golang 1.15 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have `fmt.Sprintf("20: %s\n", str)` within your http handler, or do you write it to somewhere? What comes to mind is that % is used in URL encoding. POST body that which is sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded` is also percent-encoded and thus can give you unexpected results

Comment: @caveman  i put  these 3 lines right into my handler during debug  (because I am trying to deal with a url that passes the string I cited as a query param).   I can verify that the filter is coming URLencoded,  and I can see that the bytes are correct.  but that fmt behavior seems a bit weird when I try to print the string.   It seems almost that its treating % in value as the format string .

Comment: That is strange, I would not expect that code the behave differently depending on where you place it. And if you pass `str` directly into `fmt.Println` to exclude printf formatting entirely?

Comment: Start by using a supported Go version.

Comment: fmt.Println on str  prints Uid $LKE '%'.   it is very weird.

Comment: @Volker cleaned, re-built and run with go1.17.3.  Same results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you want to check the http request for debugging. You would be better served using httputil.DumpRequest. It will dump the whole request for you to have a look at including the bits your having trouble getting at with fmt.Sprintf.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Setting the second paramater to true will dump the body as well
    dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
    fmt.Println(string(dump))

}
```